# Tkinter how to keep the insert on screen when using mouse wheel

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, mouseevent, mousewheel

In Tkinter, how do I keep the text insert on-screen (in a Text widget) while scrolling in the Text widget with the mouse wheel?

Comment: If you're curious what the downvotes are for, they are probably because of a misunderstanding (they thought my answer was part of my question, and they thought it didn't answer the question for some unknown reason, but both beliefs are quite false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example *answer* to the question in code. This is not part of the question. It is the answer. I'm sure there are more ways to answer it (so that's why I wrote, 'an example' answer).

```
from tkinter import *

…

def create_widgets(self):
    …
    self.textWidget.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel) #Windows mouse wheel
    self.textWidget.bind("<Button-4>", self.mouse_wheel) #Linux mouse wheel
    self.textWidget.bind("<Button-5>", self.mouse_wheel) #Linux mouse wheel (one is for scrolling up and one is for scrolling down, in Linux)

def mouse_wheel(self, event):
    self.textWidget.mark_set(INSERT, "current display linestart") #display makes it uses display lines (as in when word wrap is on in case you have a line that spans a lot of 'display' lines)
    #Don't add return "break" here unless you want to write the entire mouse wheel functionality yourself.
```

This code uses `mark_set` to position the insert at the `"current display linestart"` (which is the start of the line where your mouse pointer is). The `mouse_wheel` method is called when you scroll the mousewheel. This is a cross-platform solution, as it provides a way to do it on both Linux and other systems (like Windows).

Comment: The answer does in fact answer the question and *was* intended to answer the question. The only reason I asked the question was to answer it with this answer (not because I needed to know). The answer is not a critique. Nor is it clarification of the question. It does work and is tested code.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more obvious that the code is an answer, and not part of the question, and explaining how it answers the question afterward.